# How can I change the back-end in Matplotlib with Django?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I am creating a webpage that displays a graph that I created in matplotlib using Django. The script runs fine running by itself, but it doesn't work in Django for some reason.

This is the error that I get:

```
This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.
```

I import matplotlib.use() on the first line, like so:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from pylab import figure, axes, pie, title
```

I use matplotlib.use('TkAgg) to fix my problems when the script wasn't in Django. I thought that the same solution would work in Django, but it gives me an error. Does anybody know how to fix the code?

My code is very long, so I'm only going to provide a snippet of it. My functions names are pretty descriptive, so I think you'll be able to intuitively understand some of the functions (this is my views.py file):

```
def index(request):
    noaaNmbr='11809'
    #for right now, this is the only active region that I'm pulling data for. When I get the graph up and running, I will make it more interactive for the user so that he can 

    urlData = "http://www.lmsal.com/hek/hcr?cmd=search-events3&outputformat=json&instrument=IRIS&noaanum="+ noaaNmbr +"&hasData=true"

    webUrl = urlopen(urlData)
    counter = 0
    data = webUrl.read().decode('utf-8')
    hekJSON = json.loads(data)
    getInfo(counter, hekJSON)

    sort()
    # Sorts the data from earliest to most recent

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 30))
    circle = Circle((0, 0), 980, facecolor='none', edgecolor=(0, 0.8, 0.8), linewidth=3, alpha=0.5)
    ax.add_patch(circle)
# Creates circular representation of the sun on the graph because that's all I really need for now

    plt.plot(xcen, ycen, color="red")
    plt.plot(xcen, ycen, 'ro', color = 'blue')
    #first plots the points in red, then draws lines between the points in blue

    plt.xlim([setXMin(hekJSON), setXMax(hekJSON)])
    plt.ylim([setYMin(hekJSON), setYMax(hekJSON)])
#sets the boundaries of the graph

    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(setXMin(hekJSON), setXMax(hekJSON), 50))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(setYMin(hekJSON), setYMax(hekJSON), 50))
#sets the ticks

    for i in range(getNumberOfEntries(hekJSON)):
        if xfov[i] != 0:
            xStart = xcen[i] - xfov[i]/14
            yStart = ycen[i] - yfov[i]/14
            ax.add_patch(Rectangle((xStart, yStart), xfov[i]/7, yfov[i]/7, facecolor='none'))

    plt.grid()

    texts = fixAnnotations(createAnnotations(hekJSON, noaaNmbr))
    adjust_text(texts, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color='k', lw=0.5))

    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)    
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

---

Comment: From what I remember.. I specify my back end in my settings.py file.. not able to look at the minute though

Comment: @Sayse This is the error that I get: This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

Comment: Without code we cannot tell you. I suggest you: 1) start a new django project from scratch and add the least code that triggers this error 2) Post *all* of the code that you are using or describe exactly how to obtain the code using django commands.

Comment: Thats probably because you're trying to set the backend more than once

Comment: Check your import tree and start from your django main script. Could it be that another file using matplotlib is imported before this one?